# pagehide event in mobile safari

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari

I need to know Is there any event that is triggered when the url is changed and the user navigates to a different url in mobile safari? I have pagehide event triggered only when the user closes the browser tab. Is there any other work around? i cant see hashchange event firing in safari as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could look at the new features of [History in HTML5](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html). There is an event called [popstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onpopstate) which will let you do the things I think you are trying to achieve.